# Backup de tabelas oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Uso o oracle 11g na versão grátis. Segundo as aulas de banco de dados com oracle, a versão grátis não permite criar banco. Pode-se criar usuário e criar as tabelas. Com base nisso, como eu faço um backup destas tabelas? 
Exemplo do comando inicial:

```
COPY FROM <db> TO <db> <opt> <tbl> {<cls>> } USING <sel>
<db> : string de banco de dados;
```

Um exemplo de nome do banco seria: `hr/hr@banco1`

Eu tenho uma tabela de nome hotel com os campos `(id, nomeHotel, endereco, qtd_quarto).`

Uma outra maneira que vi na internet é com `expdp`:

Criando diretório:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dp AS '...\datapump';  
GRANT EXP_FULL_DATABASE  to system;  
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dp to system;
```

Este diretório é no explorador de arquivos do sistema ou é do sgbd?

para exportar:

```
expdp systen/pasword@db10g full=Y directory=dp dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

Algumas observações:

Criei um usuário de nome andre e, conectado neste usuário, criei as tabelas. Observei que nos comandos o usuário é system. Se eu fizer com o usuário system, copio minhas tabelas? Ou tenho que fazer conectado no meu usuário?

A senha que cadastrei na instalação é root. Logo conecto: `connect andre/root`

Comment: essa versão tem o EXP? Se você digitar EXP na linha de comando o ORACLE responde?

Comment: @Reginaldo Rigo
 editei a pergunta. Eu testei o comando referido, mas não consegui fazer o backup.

Comment: Não sei que versão é essa. Mas você disse que criou o usuário andre e criou tabelas desse usuário, portanto isso é um banco. Digite o comando:  ´exp  andre/root@db10g file=backup.dmp´ e veja se ele não criou o arquivo backup.dmp na pasta em que você esta.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que um backup lógico (dump), gerado através do utilitário EXPDP, seja a opção mais simples.

O diretório utilizado como destino do dump deve existir no sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional e ser referenciado no banco de dados por um objeto do tipo Directory.

Criando um diretório no sistema operacional (use o terminal):

```
# mkdir /u02/DPUMP
```

Criando um diretório no banco de dados (use um client, como o SQLPlus ou o Oracle SQL Developer):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS '/u02/DPUMP';
```

Conceda os seguintes privilégios para o usuário de banco de dados informado na chamada do EXPDP:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR TO "U_DPUMP";
GRANT EXP_FULL_DATABASE to "U_DPUMP";
```

Caso você deseje utilizar o mesmo usuário para importar dumps, também conceda esse privilégio:

```
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO "U_DPUMP";
```

Apesar do usuário SYSTEM já possuir tais privilégios, por motivos de segurança, em um ambiente de produção, não o utilize para essa finalidade. Crie um novo usuário e conceda os privilégios informados acima.

Para exportar todos os esquemas do banco de dados (use o terminal):

```
# expdp U_DPUMP/654321@XE full=y directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=dump_full_20170331_0800.dmp logfile=expdp_full_20170331_0800.log
```

Para exportar um esquema do banco de dados (use o terminal):

```
# expdp U_DPUMP/654321@XE schemas=NOME_ESQUEMA directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=dump_nomeesquema_20170331_0800.dmp logfile=expdp_nomeesquema_20170331_0800.log
```

Para exportar uma tabela de um esquema do banco de dados (use o terminal):

```
# expdp U_DPUMP/654321@XE tables=NOME_ESQUEMA.NOME_TABELA directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=dump_nomeesquema_nometabela_20170331_0800.dmp logfile=expdp_nomeesquema_nometabela_20170331_0800.log
```

Comment: Davy mas se já existir uma pasta no servidor linux para salvar os backups como faço só para apontar e fazer o backup? OBS: Nunca mexi no oracle só sql server